# Setting ID's via Javascript (KeywordScript)

Tags: javascript, html, search, keyword

I'm working on this assignment for school but there's a logic somewhere I can't find. I'm almost 100% sure it's the `setElemId()` function which is supposed to set and return the element id but it keeps returning nothing and when I set the `href` for the quick link, it just sets the `#` and not the `ID`.

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div id="page">
      <div id="logo"><img src="hlogo.jpg" alt="Historic Documents" /></div>
      <div id="logosub">Department of History<br />Midwest University</div>

      <div id="doc">
         <h1 id="doctitle">The Federalist Papers <br />No. 10</h1>
         <p id="docsubtitle">The Union as a Safeguard Against 
            Domestic Faction and Insurrection<br />From the New York Packet. Friday, 
            November 23, 1787.</p>

         <p id="intro">To the people of the state of New York:</p>

         <p id="firstp">Among the numerous advantages promised by a well-constructed 
            Union, none deserves to be more accurately developed than its 
            tendency to break and control the violence of faction. The friend of 
            distresses under which we labor have been erroneously charged on the 
         </p>

         <p>By a <dfn id="firstkey">faction</dfn>, I understand a number of 
            citizens, whether amounting to a majority or a minority of the whole, 
            interest, adversed to the rights of other citizens, or to the permanent 
            and aggregate interests of the community.</p>

         <p>The other point of difference is, the greater number of citizens and 
            extent of territory which may be brought within the compass of 
            the former than in the latter. The smaller the society, the fewer 
         </p>

      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
   if (object.attachEvent)
       object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
   else if (object.addEventListener)
       object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

addEvent(window, "load", makeKeyWordBox, false);

// Returns an array of Text
function makeElemList(elem)
{
    var elemList = document.getElementsByTagName('dfn');
    var elemTextArr = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++)
        elemTextArr[i] = elemList[i].innerText.toLowerCase();

    elemTextArr.sort();
    return elemTextArr;
}

// Searches for and returns a single ID
function setElemId(elem, elemText)
{
    var elemList = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
    var elemTextArr = new Array();
    var elemId;

    for(var i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++)
    {
        elemTextArr[i] = elemList[i].innerText.toLowerCase();

        if(elemTextArr[i] == elemText)
        {
            if(elemList[i].id = null)
            {
                elemId = elemText + i;
                elemList[i].setAttribute('id', elemId);
                return elemId;
            }
            else
            {
                alert(elemList[i].id);
                elemId = elemList[i].id;
                return elemId;
            }
        }
    }
}

function makeKeyWordBox()
{
    var keywords = makeElemList('dfn');
    var historyDoc = document.getElementById('doc');
    var keywordBoxTitle = document.createElement('h1');
        keywordBoxTitle.innerText = "Keywords";
    var keywordBox = document.createElement('div');
        keywordBox.id = "keywords";
        keywordBox.appendChild(keywordBoxTitle);
    var ulList = document.createElement('ul');
        keywordBox.appendChild(ulList);

    for(var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++)
    {
        var linkId = setElemId('dfn', keywords[i]);
        var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
        var newLink = document.createElement('a');
            newLink.innerText = keywords[i];
            newLink.href = "#" + linkId;
        newListItem.appendChild(newLink);
        ulList.appendChild(newListItem);
    }

    historyDoc.insertBefore(keywordBox, historyDoc.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: I've been going through and alerting out different parts of the function to figure out where it's gone wrong and it will hit the if statements but it will either a) always be false (like it has an ID already set) or b) just not create the id. I've updated my question with the current problem I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"it will hit the if statements but it will either a) always be false (like it has an ID already set)"*

Try changing:

```
if(elemList[i].id = null)
```

to:

```
if(!elemList[i].id)
```

You were assigning the `id` to `null` rather than comparing it to `null` (you used `=` when you meant `==` or `===`), and then the `if` would evaluate that as `null` (falsy) and go into the `else` case each time.

Also I don't think you want to compare to `null` anyway, because an `id` that wasn't set won't be `null` (when I tried it an unset `id` was an empty string, `""`). Easier to just use the `!` operator to test if `id` is "falsy".

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be searching for an exact match of the keywords. Since none of your elements contain exactly the keywords you're looking for (instead they contain text) there are no matches.

Instead, try `if( elemTextArr[i].indexOf(elemText) > -1)`

So note that you don't appear to be converting the search terms to lowercase, so if I type in an uppercase letter I won't get any matches.

Comment: I'm converting them to lowercase as I'm testing them in my loop. Still a no-go with your code. Thanks though!